# How to manipulate URL on link click in Android WebView

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-webview

I pulled a website to a `WebView` via HTTP GET.  The problem is that the website isn't formatted for mobile.  I found that if I edit the HTML, I can comment out the scripting that makes the left pane on the site.

Method:
Download page to string, search string for and replace first substring `<link` with `<!--`, write to file, and load into the `WebView`.

That works great until it comes to a link. Clicking on it causes the `WebView` to attempt to load `file:///index.php/Whatever_the_page_was`.

What I want to do is capture that link request and change the `file:///` part to `www.wurmpedia.com`, and then run it through my parser to remove the script like the first, and repeat the process on any other link click that follows.

I could not find any other way to pull this off and this is what I made up. Any help would be appreciated, either through URL modification or with a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about intercepting the link request using

[WebView.shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: OMG I can't believe this. Thanks for your quick response. While I was looking for how to get shouldInterceptRequest to work, I stumbled upon the idea of making my shouldOverrideUrlLoading to do more than just use my webview. Here's what I did: `@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
            {
             if (url.contains("file:///")){
              webView.loadUrl(getHtml("http://www.wurmpedia.com/"+url.substring(8)));
                return false;
            }`

Comment: I can't believe it was such a simple answer. Thanks for getting me on the right track @chinloong!